# What could be wrong if my BootReceiver successfully receives broadcast but my Android app is not opening after boot in API 31 or above?

Tags: java, android

I want to open my app on android boot in Android api 31 or above.

I have a bootbroadcast reciever and it successfully received the broadcast.
But it does not open my app.

Here is AndroidManifest
I add queries for my app to be open.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.bootopen" />
    </queries>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.bootopen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is BootReceiver
By using i checked boot completed or not and i got boot completed log.
I use intent flags.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if((intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) || (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_REBOOT)) {
            Log.v("Tag","Boot Completed");
            Intent openIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.bootopen");
            openIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
            context.startActivity(openIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna open my app after boot